# NLTK CFG No spaces between non terminals

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar

I want to define a CFG txt file to read into NLTK using `nltk.CFG.fromstring()`. Thing is, when I define rules, I want to make rules that don't output spaces between non terminals. For example, say I have this grammar:

```
X -> TENS ONES
TENS -> '二十' | '三十' | '四十' | '五十' | '六十' | '七十' | '八十' | '九十'
ONES -> '一' | '二' | '三' | '四' | '五' | '六' | '七' | '八' | '九'
```

If I want the word "二十一", I cannot generate it because TENS ONES will insert a space and make '二十 一". If I instead make the rule as `X -> TENSONES`, TENSONES is treated as one non-terminal, not two and thus there is no parse. Is there a way I can use two non terminals in a production without the need of a space between them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to make this work only for some non-terminals but by itself `nltk.parse.generate()` produces a list and does not insert any spaces.

An example from https://www.nltk.org/howto/generate.html adds spaces when printing the result:

```
for sentence in generate(grammar, n=10):
    print(' '.join(sentence))
```

so using an empty string instead `print(''.join(sentence))` will output all tokens without any spaces in between. Naturally now you will have to add spaces as tokens in grammar:

```
S -> NP ' ' VP
NP -> Det ' ' N
...
```